# Matching array keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array,

```
Array
(
    [campaign_title] => adasdasdasddsad
    [campaign_keyword] => asdsadasdasdasdasd
    [introduction] => asdasdasdasdasdasdsa
    [campaign_headline] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdasdasdasdasdasdad
        )

    [article] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadas
        )
    [save_multiple] => Save
)
```

Basically I need away to send the the campaign_headline and article array to a DB so that each headline and article are saved to the same row, then the next headline and article are saved to the same row etc

Comment: It'd be interesting to know what you consider a match (Same index? Same position?) and what's the code supposed to do when you don't have the same amount of headlines and articles.

Comment: You will always have the same amount of headlines and articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($x['campaign_headline'] as $key => $headline)
{
    store_into_db($headline, $x['article'][$key]);
}

function store_into_db($headline, $article)
{
    /* there you must store article into DB, i can write this code but i must more infomraiton about, db server type and tables password etc. */
}
```

Comment: for beter optimisation put `sizeof($x['campaign_headline'])` outside the loop

Comment: for better reading, use `foreach($campaign['campaign_headline] as $i => $headline)`

Comment: @Dobiatowski: This is not a optimisation because sizeof working in O(1) not in O(n) time, then this is doesn't meater

Comment: It does matter, because calling a function is far more expensive than accessing the value of a variable. But foreach is even faster ;)